# Tridion Core Service endpoint

Tags: 2011, core-service

I'm using the Core Service Client to get a list of keywords by a given category. However when viewing the page I get the following error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Tridion instance is SP1, I've been reading the documentation on http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) but can't seem to work out how to configure the end point in my web.config. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to grab the endpoints (and binding settings) from the file %TRIDION_HOME%\bin\client\Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll.config on a server with Tridion installed on it.

Mihai Cădariu also has a good post [Core Service Client Sample Code](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/core-service-client-sample-code.html#!/2012/03/core-service-client-sample-code.html) on how to programmatically instantiate the client without defining the endpoints and bindings in a configuration file.