# Publishing Taxonomy to broker database

Tags: content-delivery, broker, taxonomy, api

Further to my recent post [Tridion Core Service endpoint](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/453/tridion-core-service-endpoint) with regard to querying the Core Service Client to retrieve a list of keywords for a given category Id, I've realized it might not be the best method to adopt.

This is because I would be accessing Tridion directly not the broker database which is bad for several reasons i.e. not having access to servers due to firewalls, category is in Tridion but not ready to be set live yet etc. Therefore I think it's best if I query the broker database instead (using CD API).

To do this the data I require needs to exist in the broker database. Publishing taxonomy looks to be quite a trivial task as it seems I only need to add an entry into the cd_storage_conf file. I have the below and restarted IIS and Tridion services but can't get it working.

```
<Item typeMapping="Taxonomy" cached="true" storageId="defaultFile"/>
```

I've had a look on SDL Live Content (Configuring content storage section) for reference.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong? I'm working with Tridion 2011 SP1 with an ORACLE database.

Comment: Please let us know what exactly isn't working - Publishing? or viewing/querying the taxonomy. You can publish Taxonomies to the FileSystem BTW - They have to go to the Broker DB

Comment: Thanks Chris, when I was publishing the category it wasn't appearing in the broker database. I've managed to get it working after restarting Com+ and the App Pool.

Comment: Please don't use Broker as a category - Nothing in Tridion is called "broker" (other than some APIs & namespaces/packages) since Tridion 2011. The database is called "Content Data Store" and the old broker API is now called the Storage API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working after restarting Com+ and the App Pool.

Comment: Did you also change your config files? Or are you saying you successfully published a taxonomy to the file system?

Comment: Even if you managed to publish it to FS (which I doubt) you won't be able to load it through the API - Also, can't see the relationship between COM+ and Content Delivery, this link was last seen on Tridion 5.3... (and back then you couldn't publish taxonomies)

Comment: I did change the config files to add a taxonomy item type. Then after restarting the App Pool, Com+, and publishing the taxonomy it appeared in the database.

Comment: The confusion is you have 'defaultFile' in your storage config file above. Have you changed this to 'defaultDb'?

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to publish Taxonomies to the file system so the storage type mapping you describe is not viable. If you have a broker database storage element in your storage conf file, map the Taxonomy type to this (eg storageId="defaultDB")